# Formula to get the maximum of an array of cells with a custom list on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet like this, with some cells having a **value** and **being merged** with the next one.

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
01 | ??? |     |     |     |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
02 |     |    LOW    |     |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
03 |     |     |     |     |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
04 |     |  MEDIUM   |     |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
05 |     |     |     |     |   HIGH    |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
06 |     |     |     |     |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I would like the cell `A1` to be the maximum of `B2`/`B4`/`E5` according to the custom sort:

- *Low* (lowest)
- *Medium*
- *High* (highest)

In case it is useful, I have a table associating a value to each one of these item. I tried to do a CSE formula with a MAX(MATCH()) but it didn't work out because they're not consecutive range.

```
ScaleTable

Scale  |  Value  |
-------+---------+
Low    | 0       |
-------+---------+
Medium | 1       |
-------+---------+
High   | 2       |
-------+---------+
```

Comment: Do you want to return the text in the different cells?  Or the value from the scale table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ScaleTable` is sorted in ascending order (e.g according to the Values column) and

If the result you want to return is the Scale (text string from the Scale column), then:

```
A1:  =INDEX(ScaleTable,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH($B$2,ScaleTable[Scale],0),0),IFERROR(MATCH($B$4,ScaleTable[Scale],0),0),IFERROR(MATCH($E$5,ScaleTable[Scale],0),0)),1)
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to return the numeric value from the `Value` column in `ScaleTable`, then merely change `column_num` argument of the `INDEX` function to 2.

If you want to return the `nth` largest, use the `LARGE` function instead of `MAX`

If the `ScaleTable` is not so sorted, then the formula would be a bit more complex.

Comment: This formula would take the maximum of the range B1:F6 and not of the cells B2/B4/E5. Unexpected value in the other cells would lead to unexpected result in A1.

Comment: @Partot did not realize you wanted to limit it to those particular cells. we'll post back later as I am going out of town just now.

Comment: @Partot See edit to restrict to just those three cells